# After manual wordpress site install, all pages accessible through the dashboard serve 404 error

Tags: wordpress

Client site was totally inaccessible. I downloaded what I thought was all I needed: wp-config, database, wp-contents and manually uploaded to a new WP install. The outcome allows me to see the frontend, access the dashboard, but thats it.

Nothing from the dashboard loads anything other than a 404.

Should I have also downloaded the wp-includes file.

At this point I feel I owe my client a whole new site, that actually has backend functionality.

Any ideas on this salvage operation or should I start recreating the site from scratch using the frontend as the "design file"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question, but let's take a look.

It is usually a mess that occurs in writing the rules of the .htaccess file and doing this may work again.

Go to Settings » General and see if you have the address you really left configured for website access.

After that, go to Settings » Permalinks. After logging in, see if you have the option you want for the Permalink Structure. Once this is done, even if your option is checked, click on the Save button (this is where you will redo the .htaccess to correct the WordPress routes).

Hope this helps